# 4 points not separable by SVM

Tags: machine-learning, svm

We know in a support vector machine:

[image]

Considering we have a linear feature mapping $\phi(x_n)=x_n$
We have 2 classes, class 1 $ t_+=+1$ the XOR problem and class 2 $t_-=-1$ and 4 points where $x_1, x_2$ are from class1 and $x_3, x_4$ are from class2.

Therefore we can write, $w=a_1x_1+a_2x_2-a_3x_3-a_4x_4$ and $a_1+a_2-a_3-a_4=0$

How can we prove the 4 points are not separable?

Comment: Wouldn't this be better suited for math.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with SVM, XOR is not linearly separable, which can be prooved in various ways. SVM is in particular, a linear model (for this phi function) so if there is **no linear discriminator** for this points, than SVM also cannot discriminate them.

The simplest proof goes like this:

1. Take a middle point (the one in the center of your four points), call it x
2. x lies on the convex hulls of both positive and negatives classes
3. Linear model separates space into **convex** subspaces
4. Take any linear model that correctly classifies both positive and negative points (your XOR), it now **has to** give the same label to each of the point inside of the convex hull, so `x` should have both positive and negative label, contradiction

Comment: -1 voter, please leave the comment. It would be nice to know what do you find incorrect about this answer